# Original class name of a proxy (without manual string manipulation)

Tags: java, class, jakarta-ee, proxy, cdi

In Java, how do you get the original class object and/or class name of a Java EE (CDI) proxy?

When using `getName()` on a proxy instance, the name returned is something like

```
com.company.employeemgmt.EmployeeManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass
```

Is there some functionaliy in Java SE (7) or EE (6) that will return either the original, unproxied class instance or its name?

I need:

```
com.company.employeemgmt.EmployeeManager
```

Of course, I could simply use string manipulation, but I would like to know if such functionality is already Java-(EE)-inbuilt.

I already found `java.reflect.Proxy`, which I could use to detect proxies:

```
public static void doSomething( Class<? implements Serializable> managerClass )
{
    if ( Proxy.isProxyClass( managerClass ) )
    {
        // unproxy how?
        managerClass = managerClass.getUnproxiedClass();
    }

    // delegate
    doSomething( managerClass.getName() );
}


public static void doSomething( String prefix )
{
    // do real work
    ...
}
```

..., but how would you dereference the original class?

**Update:**

The trick would be to access `MyUtil.doSomething( EmployeeManager.class )` (or  `MyUtil.doSomething( EmployeeManager.class.getName() )`), but I would like to use/pass `MyUtil.doSomething( this.getClass() )` (or  `MyUtil.doSomething( this.getClass().getName() )`) from all clients as this code can be copied around without manual changes.

Comment: Did you try managerClass.getDeclaringClass() or managerClass.getEnclosingClass()?

Comment: Nothing you do here would be portable or stable. The proxy is really only "related to" the other class.  CDI does not dictate what technology is used to proxy or any way to get from a proxy to Class details of the Managed Bean (although you could start with the BeanManager API and work forwards rather than backwards from an Object)

Comment: The customer is relying on CDI using Weld anyway, so using that approach seems fine. In other cases I agree.

Comment: CDI might have had this ability. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-10 unfortunately it was closed.

Comment: Too bad it was closed.

Answer (score 6):

Since the proxy class inherits from the original class, I think that you can obtain the original class by getting the proxy superclass.

Answer (score 4):

*It depends*. You can get the [InvocationHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) for a proxy using [Proxy.getInvocationHandler(manager)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#getInvocationHandler%28java.lang.Object%29). Alas, InvocationHandler is an interface with only one `invoke` method and with no feature that lets you get a target class; it all depends on the implementation.

As an example the CXF web servcie framework has a [Client](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-api/2.7.0/org/apache/cxf/endpoint/Client.java#Client) and uses a [ClientProxy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple/2.7.0/org/apache/cxf/frontend/ClientProxy.java#ClientProxy) as an associated invocation handler, you can get the Client as such:

```
ClientProxy handler = (ClientProxy)Proxy.getInvocationHandler(proxiedObject);
Client client = handler.getClient();
```

To add insult to injury, it seems that the [WeldInvocationHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.ws/jbossws-jboss600/4.0.0.Alpha1/org/jboss/webservices/integration/weld/WeldInvocationHandler.java) that you are probably using simply delegates the call to a [org.jboss.wsf.spi.invocation.InvocationHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.ws/jbossws-spi/2.0.0.Alpha2/org/jboss/wsf/spi/invocation/InvocationHandler.java#InvocationHandler) that that it stores its delegate in a private field. So you need to do quite some magic with reflection to find out the actual class of the target object.

Answer (score 0):

Since proxy implements interfaces it proxies, you can use `Class<?>[] Class.getInterfaces()`
to find out proxied class(es).

```
private Class<?> findProxiedClass(Object proxiedObject) {

    Class<?> proxiedClass = proxiedObject.getClass();

    if (proxiedObject instanceof Proxy) {
        Class<?>[] ifaces = proxiedClass.getInterfaces();
        if (ifaces.length == 1) {
            proxiedClass = ifaces[0];
        } else {
            // We need some selection strategy here
            // or return all of them
            proxiedClass = ifaces[ifaces.length - 1];
        }
    }
    return proxiedClass;
}
```

Test it with

```
@Test
public void testProxies() {

    InvocationHandler handler = new InvocationHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
                throws Throwable {
            return null;
        }
    };

    RandomAccess proxiedIface = (RandomAccess) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            RandomAccess.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] { RandomAccess.class },
            handler);

    Assert.assertEquals(RandomAccess.class, findProxiedClass(proxiedIface));
    Assert.assertEquals(Object.class, findProxiedClass(new Object()));
}
```